# Storing dynamic Pivot result into a temporary table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have the following schema and sample data.

```
create table MyTable
(
    Id int,
    Year int,
    Channel varchar(10),
    Payments int
)

insert into MyTable values 
               (1,2012,'HV',100),
               (1,2014,'HV',56),
               (2,2012,'NL',17000)
               (2,2012,'HV',495), 
               (3,2013,'HV',565)
```

Now I want to create and insert dynamic pivot data in a temporary table. I am able to create the pivot data as the demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/CXX71736).

But I want to store this data into a temporary table. What I have tried is as below.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '    
if object_id(''tempdb..##TempTable'') is not null
begin
    drop table ##TempTable
end

create table ##TempTable([Id] int null, ' + 
            Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)) + ' Varchar(20) null'            
            From [dbo].MyTable
            Order By 1 
            For XML Path('')),1,1,'')+ ')
INSERT INTO ##TempTable
Select *
 From (
        Select A.Id
              ,B.*
         From  [dbo].[MyTable] A
         Cross Apply ( values ( Id, Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)
                     )) B (Item,Value)
      ) S
 Pivot (sum([Payments]) For Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year) in 
 (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year))                                                               
                                               From [dbo].MyTable
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'

select @SQL

Exec(@SQL);

SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
```

It is giving me the following error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near '+'.

When printing the dynamic query it is giving the following result.

```
if object_id('tempdb..##TempTable') is not null  
begin      
    drop table ##TempTable  
end    
create table ##TempTable([Id] int null, [HV2012] Varchar(20) null,[HV2013] Varchar(20) null,[HV2014] Varchar(20) null,[NL2012] Varchar(20) null)  
INSERT INTO ##TempTable  
    Select *   From ( Select A.Id ,B.* From  [dbo].[MyTable] A 
        Cross Apply ( values ( Id, Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year) )) B (Item,Value) ) S   
        Pivot (sum([Payments]) For Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year) in ([HV2012],[HV2013],[HV2014],[NL2012]) ) p
```

Comment: Please add to your question what you get when you `PRINT(@SQL)` before executing it.

Comment: I'm betting it's `Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)` in the pivot. I don't think you can do that. Since you are creating this from the `cross apply`, changing it to `[Value]` should work. Just something to try

Comment: @TabAlleman I have added dynamic query print output.

Comment: I think maybe you need to make `Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)` part of the dynamic calculation, and not have it still uncalculated in the `@SQL` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `apply` then why you need further same logic in `PIVOT` (i.e. `Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)`) which is already available in `apply`.

So, i would use `Value` instead in `PIVOT` :

```
. . . 
Pivot (sum([Payments]) For [Value] in ([HV2012],[HV2013],[HV2014],[NL2012]) ) p,
```

So, your updated `Dynamic SQL` would be :

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '    
if object_id(''tempdb..##TempTable'') is not null
begin
    drop table ##TempTable
end

create table ##TempTable([Id] int null, ' + 
            Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)) + ' Varchar(20) null'            
            From [dbo].MyTable
            Order By 1 
            For XML Path('')),1,1,'')+ ')
INSERT INTO ##TempTable
Select *
 From (
        Select A.ID, A.Payments
              ,B.*
         From  [dbo].MyTable a 
         Cross Apply ( values ( Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)
                     )) B ([Value])
      ) S
 Pivot (sum([Payments]) For [Value] in 
 (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year))                                                               
                                               From #tm
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'

print @sql

Exec(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
```

I have made no of changes as there are many correction needs to be done prior to execution.

Comment: @SurajKumar. . . That because of you have used `A.ID` in `inner select` statement.

Comment: @SurajKumar. . . As i can see nothing is wrong in the code as i have compiled & executed in `SQL Server` to verify.